# Minesweeper in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, minesweeper

Out of boredom I decided to make simple minesweeper in python. I decided to do it using only libraries which are included in standard installation on Windows.

I have overall been coding in Python for a while now, but decided to give my code for review to see whatever my coding skills can be improved.

```
import tkinter, configparser, random, os, tkinter.messagebox, tkinter.simpledialog

window = tkinter.Tk()

window.title("Minesweeper")

#prepare default values

rows = 10
cols = 10
mines = 10

field = []
buttons = []

colors = ['#FFFFFF', '#0000FF', '#008200', '#FF0000', '#000084', '#840000', '#008284', '#840084', '#000000']

gameover = False
customsizes = []


def createMenu():
    menubar = tkinter.Menu(window)
    menusize = tkinter.Menu(window, tearoff=0)
    menusize.add_command(label="small (10x10 with 10 mines)", command=lambda: setSize(10, 10, 10))
    menusize.add_command(label="medium (20x20 with 40 mines)", command=lambda: setSize(20, 20, 40))
    menusize.add_command(label="big (35x35 with 120 mines)", command=lambda: setSize(35, 35, 120))
    menusize.add_command(label="custom", command=setCustomSize)
    menusize.add_separator()
    for x in range(0, len(customsizes)):
        menusize.add_command(label=str(customsizes[x][0])+"x"+str(customsizes[x][1])+" with "+str(customsizes[x][2])+" mines", command=lambda customsizes=customsizes: setSize(customsizes[x][0], customsizes[x][1], customsizes[x][2]))
    menubar.add_cascade(label="size", menu=menusize)
    menubar.add_command(label="exit", command=lambda: window.destroy())
    window.config(menu=menubar)


def setCustomSize():
    global customsizes
    r = tkinter.simpledialog.askinteger("Custom size", "Enter amount of rows")
    c = tkinter.simpledialog.askinteger("Custom size", "Enter amount of columns")
    m = tkinter.simpledialog.askinteger("Custom size", "Enter amount of mines")
    while m > r*c:
        m = tkinter.simpledialog.askinteger("Custom size", "Maximum mines for this dimension is: " + str(r*c) + "\nEnter amount of mines")
    customsizes.insert(0, (r,c,m))
    customsizes = customsizes[0:5]
    setSize(r,c,m)
    createMenu()

def setSize(r,c,m):
    global rows, cols, mines
    rows = r
    cols = c
    mines = m
    saveConfig()
    restartGame()

def saveConfig():
    global rows, cols, mines
    #configuration
    config = configparser.SafeConfigParser()
    config.add_section("game")
    config.set("game", "rows", str(rows))
    config.set("game", "cols", str(cols))
    config.set("game", "mines", str(mines))
    config.add_section("sizes")
    config.set("sizes", "amount", str(min(5,len(customsizes))))
    for x in range(0,min(5,len(customsizes))):
        config.set("sizes", "row"+str(x), str(customsizes[x][0]))
        config.set("sizes", "cols"+str(x), str(customsizes[x][1]))
        config.set("sizes", "mines"+str(x), str(customsizes[x][2]))

    with open("config.ini", "w") as file:
        config.write(file)

def loadConfig():
    global rows, cols, mines, customsizes
    config = configparser.SafeConfigParser()
    config.read("config.ini")
    rows = config.getint("game", "rows")
    cols = config.getint("game", "cols")
    mines = config.getint("game", "mines")
    amountofsizes = config.getint("sizes", "amount")
    for x in range(0, amountofsizes):
        customsizes.append((config.getint("sizes", "row"+str(x)), config.getint("sizes", "cols"+str(x)), config.getint("sizes", "mines"+str(x))))

def prepareGame():
    global rows, cols, mines, field
    field = []
    for x in range(0, rows):
        field.append([])
        for y in range(0, cols):
            #add button and init value for game
            field[x].append(0)
    #generate mines
    for _ in range(0, mines):
        x = random.randint(0, rows-1)
        y = random.randint(0, cols-1)
        #prevent spawning mine on top of each other
        while field[x][y] == -1:
            x = random.randint(0, rows-1)
            y = random.randint(0, cols-1)
        field[x][y] = -1
        if x != 0:
            if y != 0:
                if field[x-1][y-1] != -1:
                    field[x-1][y-1] = int(field[x-1][y-1]) + 1
            if field[x-1][y] != -1:
                field[x-1][y] = int(field[x-1][y]) + 1
            if y != cols-1:
                if field[x-1][y+1] != -1:
                    field[x-1][y+1] = int(field[x-1][y+1]) + 1
        if y != 0:
            if field[x][y-1] != -1:
                field[x][y-1] = int(field[x][y-1]) + 1
        if y != cols-1:
            if field[x][y+1] != -1:
                field[x][y+1] = int(field[x][y+1]) + 1
        if x != rows-1:
            if y != 0:
                if field[x+1][y-1] != -1:
                    field[x+1][y-1] = int(field[x+1][y-1]) + 1
            if field[x+1][y] != -1:
                field[x+1][y] = int(field[x+1][y]) + 1
            if y != cols-1:
                if field[x+1][y+1] != -1:
                    field[x+1][y+1] = int(field[x+1][y+1]) + 1

def prepareWindow():
    global rows, cols, buttons
    tkinter.Button(window, text="Restart", command=restartGame).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=cols, sticky=tkinter.N+tkinter.W+tkinter.S+tkinter.E)
    buttons = []
    for x in range(0, rows):
        buttons.append([])
        for y in range(0, cols):
            b = tkinter.Button(window, text=" ", width=2, command=lambda x=x,y=y: clickOn(x,y))
            b.bind("<Button-3>", lambda e, x=x, y=y:onRightClick(x, y))
            b.grid(row=x+1, column=y, sticky=tkinter.N+tkinter.W+tkinter.S+tkinter.E)
            buttons[x].append(b)

def restartGame():
    global gameover
    gameover = False
    #destroy all - prevent memory leak
    for x in window.winfo_children():
        if type(x) != tkinter.Menu:
            x.destroy()
    prepareWindow()
    prepareGame()

def clickOn(x,y):
    global field, buttons, colors, gameover, rows, cols
    if gameover:
        return
    buttons[x][y]["text"] = str(field[x][y])
    if field[x][y] == -1:
        buttons[x][y]["text"] = "*"
        buttons[x][y].config(background='red', disabledforeground='black')
        gameover = True
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Game Over", "You have lost.")
        #now show all other mines
        for _x in range(0, rows):
            for _y in range(cols):
                if field[_x][_y] == -1:
                    buttons[_x][_y]["text"] = "*"
    else:
        buttons[x][y].config(disabledforeground=colors[field[x][y]])
    if field[x][y] == 0:
        buttons[x][y]["text"] = " "
        #now repeat for all buttons nearby which are 0... kek
        autoClickOn(x,y)
    buttons[x][y]['state'] = 'disabled'
    buttons[x][y].config(relief=tkinter.SUNKEN)
    checkWin()

def autoClickOn(x,y):
    global field, buttons, colors, rows, cols
    if buttons[x][y]["state"] == "disabled":
        return
    if field[x][y] != 0:
        buttons[x][y]["text"] = str(field[x][y])
    else:
        buttons[x][y]["text"] = " "
    buttons[x][y].config(disabledforeground=colors[field[x][y]])
    buttons[x][y].config(relief=tkinter.SUNKEN)
    buttons[x][y]['state'] = 'disabled'
    if field[x][y] == 0:
        if x != 0 and y != 0:
            autoClickOn(x-1,y-1)
        if x != 0:
            autoClickOn(x-1,y)
        if x != 0 and y != cols-1:
            autoClickOn(x-1,y+1)
        if y != 0:
            autoClickOn(x,y-1)
        if y != cols-1:
            autoClickOn(x,y+1)
        if x != rows-1 and y != 0:
            autoClickOn(x+1,y-1)
        if x != rows-1:
            autoClickOn(x+1,y)
        if x != rows-1 and y != cols-1:
            autoClickOn(x+1,y+1)

def onRightClick(x,y):
    global buttons
    if gameover:
        return
    if buttons[x][y]["text"] == "?":
        buttons[x][y]["text"] = " "
        buttons[x][y]["state"] = "normal"
    elif buttons[x][y]["text"] == " " and buttons[x][y]["state"] == "normal":
        buttons[x][y]["text"] = "?"
        buttons[x][y]["state"] = "disabled"

def checkWin():
    global buttons, field, rows, cols
    win = True
    for x in range(0, rows):
        for y in range(0, cols):
            if field[x][y] != -1 and buttons[x][y]["state"] == "normal":
                win = False
    if win:
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Gave Over", "You have won.")

if os.path.exists("config.ini"):
    loadConfig()
else:
    saveConfig()

createMenu()

prepareWindow()
prepareGame()
window.mainloop()
```

This minesweeper creates `settings.ini` in the same location where from script was run.

Answer (score 7):

A few superficial things:

- Games like this are perfect for **object oriented** code. Some obvious classes for a Minesweeper game would include for example `Game`, `Board` and `Tile`.
- **Avoid `global`s.** These helpfully often disappear naturally when using OO.
- **Pass the code through `pycodestyle`** and correct everything it reports. Other Pythonistas will thank you, even though it may feel unfamiliar and even arbitrary some times.
- **Avoid single letter names** such as `b`. Even `x` and `y` can be misleading in your specific case - a mathematically inclined person would think of them as offsets from the bottom left, but it looks like in your case it's actually an offset from the *top* left since they are used as `row` and `column` in `prepareWindow`.
- **Use constants for magic values** such as configuration variables and the minimum number of mines (5).
- **Add spacing to your `longvariablenames`** to make them easier to read.

Comment: Just to note: doing point 1 (going OO) should fix point 2 (use of globals)

Answer (score 3):

Also, you can use `random.sample(num_tiles, num_mines)` to avoid repetitive mine spawning.

Comment: While this point is correct, it's not quite obvious why the current code for spawning mines isn't actually "properly random". This answer would be a lot better if you explained why using `random.sample` is better than using `random.randint` twice with checking for duplicates :)

Comment: thanks for the feedback, but i don't see how it's not properly random there.

Comment: The key here is realizing that the two calls to radom.randint in succession are not as independent as one would want for a fully random distribution in 2d space. With sufficiently many trials, you'd see the properties of the underlying PRNG, Since python 3.2 the distribution is better, but looking at the [relevant documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) suggests that subsequent calls to `random.randint` are still not perfectly independent enough to replace `random.sample`. TBQH in practice that property doesn't matter too much for non-cryptographic uses.

Comment: so it's something like a stream cipher with entropy limited to key length?

Comment: that's basically how it works, yes

Answer (score 1):

In the original minesweeper game, it was impossible to lose on the first try because the mine (if you were unlucky enough to click it) moved to another tile. I think this would be another improvement.